# Upload image in Flask

Tags: python, flask, image-uploading

I have to upload some images in static folder of my project directory, but i don't know how to say it to my code. In the follow code.py i'm able to upload an image and store it in the project directory at the same level of static folder, but i would that this image can be store INSIDE static folder.

```
@app.route('/uploader', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      f = request.files['file']

      f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
      return render_template('end.html')
```

What i have to do?? Thanks guys

Comment: It would be nice if you could accept an answer as a correct answer

Answer (score 59):

you need to define the `upload folder`

from the `flask` documentation

```
import os
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/path/to/the/uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit a empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/

So your code would be `UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/path/to/static/images'` or something like that

Comment: This and the link were hugely helpful to get an implementation working. Thanks

Comment: This will work only if you want to upload just one image. If the user select 2 or more images, only the first file will be uploaded. How can be possible upload more than 2 images at the same time?

Comment: @FrancoGil pass a couple files over to flask through javascript/html then loop through them with a for loop. If I recall correctly, you can specify allowing multiple files hence the loop

Comment: Thanks @DavidFrick, I forget to estabilsh that I found a solution to this tinny issue.

Comment: ```def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS```

Answer (score 16):

1. your form's `enctype` should be `multipart/form-data` (otherwise it does not work):

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form>
```

2. You should specify upload folder (otherwise it does not work):

`app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = '/path/to/the/uploads'`

3. You should specify a name for your file input (otherwise it does not work):

```
<input type="file" name="file1">
```

4. you should manually save the file with file `save()` method:

```
path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file1.filename)
file1.save(path)
```

4. Simple full example:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request

UPLOAD_FOLDER = './upload'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file1' not in request.files:
            return 'there is no file1 in form!'
        file1 = request.files['file1']
        path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file1.filename)
        file1.save(path)
        return path

        return 'ok'
    return '''
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file1">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
    '''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

5. Detailed full example:
   https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/

Answer (score 3):

Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to form that contains your `input type=file`
After that,

```
from os.path import join, dirname, realpath
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

UPLOADS_PATH = join(dirname(realpath(__file__)), 'static\\img')

        

if request.files['image'].filename != '':
                image = request.files['image']
                image.save(os.path.join(UPLOADS_PATH, secure_filename(image.filename)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to first store the image jpeg or jpg in a static folder
[image]
[image]
inside the static folder the image is stored
[image]

then in the html file

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='Hermes.png')}}" align="middle" />
```

add this code line

In app.py the code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request


# Route for handling the login page logic
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/register')
def register():
    return render_template('register.html')

@app.route('/registerV')
def registerV():
    return render_template('registerV.html')
```

In register.html the code

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="bd-example" align="middle">
            <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='Hermes.png')}}" align="middle" />
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, @PYA 's code won't work for me, but I made a small change:
I used `'path/to/the/uploads'` instead of `'/path/to/the/uploads'` and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need "/" for folders in project's folder:

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/images'
```